# Pycharm after executing, move the cursor to console

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, after hitting debug, I'd like the cursor to jump on the debug [tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window.html) automatically.

I have configured to use [python console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/interactive-console.html) when I hit run. I'd like the cursor to go to python console directly as well after running the code (a feature in Spyder).

At the moment, I do it manually by either my mouse or key shortcut. Can I somehow make this a default option after running?

Comment: Your description is vague, what are the *"debug console"* and the *"python console"* you refer to?

Comment: I have edited the above question for clarity. Sorry for the vagueness earlier. Hope this clears what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, to do that, but i am not aware of how to rebind it.